# prestashop maintenance page custom css dont work

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

i am newbie in prestashop module development, i want to make a module to display a custom page for maintenance page, for this i have create a hook and added it to maintenance tpl file of my theme, when i active the maintenance mode the html of my custom page display normally but it does not load neither css or js files associated with my module, when i inspect the page it shows that it does not load this files
here is my code

```
<?php
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) {
    exit;
}
class Sd_Coming_Soon extends Module{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->name                  =   "sd_coming_soon";
        $this->author                =   "name";
        $this->version               =   "1.0.0";
        $this->bootstrap             =   true;
        parent::__construct();
        $this->displayName           =   $this->l("Sd Coming Soon page");
        $this->description           =   $this->l("This module will add Coming soon page with countdown");
        $this->ps_version_compliancy =   array("min" => "1.7", "max" => _PS_VERSION_);
    }
    public function install(){
        if (!parent::install())
            return false;
        if (!$this->registerHook('displayComingSoon') or !$this->registerHook('displayMaintenance'))
            return false;
        $this->registerHook('displayMaintenance');
        return true;       
   }
   public function uninstall(){
       if(!parent::uninstall())
            return false;
       return true;
   }
   public function hookDisplayComingSoon($params){


        return $this->display(__FILE__,'views/templates/hook/coming_soon.tpl');
   }
   public function hookDisplayMaintenance($params){    
        $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'views/css/coming_soon.css', 'all');
        $this->context->controller->addJs($this->_path.'views/js/coming_soon.js', 'all');
   }

}
```

so i have try to add the css and js path hard coded into the maintenance tpl file, the links show up in the page when i inspect it but it does not work, the page display only raw html without any styles

Comment: Place the addCSS and addJS in hookDisplayComingSoon.

Comment: i tried this but not load either

Answer (score 0):

Add them in header, like:

```
public function hookHeader()
{
    $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path.'/views/js/front.js');
    $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'/views/css/front.css');
}
```

Comment: it does not work, i think the header hook not work in maintenance page at all

Comment: when hooked in the header do you see the front.css listed as loaded on the page html source? If so, do you see the styles within front.css in the dev tools?

Comment: no i dont see that file, actullay the head only load <style> and <script> tags with some inline codes inside

Comment: did you really registered the header hook in the install function with $this->registerHook('header')? Do you see your module hooked there when you check in backoffice?

Answer (score 0):

Use the correct Hook

**Register Hook:**

```
$this->registerHook('displayHeader')
```

**Call your files**

```
public function hookDisplayHeader()
{
    $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path.'PATH.js');
    $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'PATH.css');
}
```

Please remember you have to reinstall your module in order to register the new hook in Prestashop

Comment: it does not load the files in the head tag

Comment: Take a look in the the original function "displayMaintenancePage()" located in "/classes/controler/FrontController.php. This might help you, probably need to create a custom controller or use an override.

Comment: i have try to hard code the css file in my maintenance tpl page, it loads in the page but it doesnt work and i dont know why, the path is corrent and when i click on it, it show's me the css code but it does not work, it's like it's ignored